# Dart: Include `params:` keyword in function/method doc

Tags: flutter, dart, documentation, dart-pub

I am trying to write documentation for this function `dropwDownList`.

```dart
/// Shows a list of dropdown taken from [model] and [context].
Widget dropDownList(ExploreEventsViewModel model, BuildContext context) {
  return DropdownButton<String>(
    key: homeModel?.keySECategoryMenu,
    value: model.chosenValue,
    isExpanded: true,
    .....
}
```

While Writing the above doc line I get this lint error.

`` Wrong doc format. Include `params:` keyword in function/method docdart(talawa_good_doc_comments) ``

Here's the Screenshot
[image]

I can't understand what they means by adding `params:` in the comment. Please explain.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a standard lint.  Are you using custom lints from some other package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This lint error is introduced by a custom lint extension inside the `Talawa` project. It forces you to abide by a specific format for your documentation. In your case, you are missing to describe all parameters to your function using the `params:` keyword. An example of a documentation passing this linter check looks like this

```
/// This function is used to do something special.
///
/// params:
/// * `input`: The input.
/// returns:
/// * `string`: An output.
string doSomething(string input) {}
```

You can find the implementation of this rule [here on github](https://github.com/PalisadoesFoundation/talawa/blob/develop/talawa_lint/lib/talawa_good_doc.dart).

Comment: Thanks, I've also found out about their lint guide here. https://docs.talawa.io/docs/developers/talawa/talawa-lint